# Signals in Java

Tags: java

I was use C++ signals

sigaction

```
struct sigaction sigact;
```

and set all attributes to use signals

now I want to use it in Java what's the equivalent in java

to the `include "signal.h"`

I have two threads:

1. one run from the beginning of the program
2. and the other run at the signal Alarm

I was implement the functionality in C++ using Signals as shown and now I want to implement it using java

Edited to put my Goal:

actually my Goal to run the second Thread When the signal arrives from the first thread

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve? Signals are possibly not the right tool.

Comment: @Mat - and if they are the right tool, then Java is the wrong language.

Comment: For 1) you don't need signals. For 2) the usual solution is to use a socket listing for simple commands on a certain port.

Comment: @usr, you're not describing your goal in enough detail. Just because you did something with signals in C++ doesn't mean you should do it using signals in Java. Please describe more precisely what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: thanks Mat, I add my Goal

Answer (score 4):

Thus sounds like a typical "[XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)".

In plain Java you have no access to OS-signal. They are platform specific and Java strifes to be platform agnostic. Also: calling Java from a signal handler with JNI might be "fun" (as explained in [Dwarf Fortress](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Fun)).

So you have to go back to the drawing board and think about what is the problem you want to solve and stop thinking about how to solve it with signals.

That said: *if* you insist on signals and are not afraid to use internal stuff which might change on a whim: Take a look at `sun.misc.Signal`.

**EDIT** Now the question made it clear, that the signalling takes place **within one JVM**. For this signals are **definitely** the wrong thing in Java.

So the simplest solution is to create and start the second thread directly from within the first thread. No signalling required.

The next best solution is to code a "rendezvous point" using `Object.wait()` in the second thread (using any object instance but the `Thread` itself) and `Object.notify()` or `notifyAll()` from the first thread. Searching for these terms in a Java tutorial will bring up enough examples.